# python3 TimeStamp off by 2 hours

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time

I'me a bit new to python but having the hardest time working with timestamps,utc and unixtime.

This example is off by 2 hours:

```
sec_in_day=86400
today = datetime.datetime.utcnow() 
print(today)

two_days_ago=today.timestamp()-(sec_in_day*2);
print("Two days ago (unix)",two_days_ago)

# Convert timestamp via 3rd party 
tool:http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

#generated unix-timestamp is 2 hours early according to 3rd party tool
```

2017-04-11 06:36:49.414133

Two days ago (unix) 1491712609.414133

Converting 1491712609.414133 via online tool gives me

Sun, 09 Apr 2017 04:36:49 GMT

Was expecting Sun, 09 Apr 2017 06:36:49 GMT

Answer (score 1):

I believe it all works as designed.

First you do:

```
today = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

which is in UTC, without daylight-savings adjustment, without local timezone adjustment.

Then you do:

```
today.timestamp()
```

Which, according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) is local time, therefore it includes an adjustment for day-light-savings, as well as local timezone.

This explains the 2 hour difference.

What you might want to look into is `today - datetime.timedelta(days=2)`

Comment: But hhave i not converted it to UCT by doing 

    datetime.datetime.utcnow()

Comment: How do I get a UTC unixtimestamp from two days ago ?

Comment: ,The utc timestamp is then still off   

   newday=today - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
   print("ND",newday)
   print("ND",newday.timestamp())

Comment: it is all in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) "Note There is no method to obtain the POSIX timestamp directly from a naive datetime instance representing UTC time. If your application uses this convention and your system timezone is not set to UTC, you can obtain the POSIX timestamp by supplying tzinfo=timezone.utc:" maybe you should not start with `.utcnow()` and use local time all the way. Eitherway, I suggest you read the docs and experiment with the different functionality of `datetime`

Answer (score 1):

This has solved my problem

```
sec_in_day=86400
today = datetime.datetime.utcnow() 

timestamp = today.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
print("Today",today)
print("Today-Re", today.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc))
print("TS",timestamp)
print("TS#2",(timestamp-(sec_in_day*2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also used below code

```
sec_in_day=86400
today = datetime.datetime.utcnow() 
print(today)

two_days_ago=today.timestamp()-(sec_in_day*2);

print("Two days ago (unix): ",datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(two_days_ago).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

In this I have used **fromtimestamp(two_days_ago).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))** function which will convert epoch time into readable form.